# Point3f instead Point2f for KeyPoint in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, c++11

Is there any way to use `Point3f` instead of `Point2f` as `KeyPoint` argument?
Here in [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html) they mentioned only Point2f, but still I want to know if there is any way to do it. Is there any other method possible?

Comment: Features are coordinates in 2-D space hence they are `Point2f`, why do you need `Point3f` here?

Comment: I am not extracting features, instead I want to pass x, y & z coordinates to `KeyPoint`.

Comment: You'd need to pass Point2f by constructing a Point2f taking just the x and y coords from your Point3f points

Comment: what's your z coordinate? Do you still need it or is it ok to drop it? Why do you want to use KeyPoint class?

Comment: @Micka I'm using code for DBSCAN from this code (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23966/density-based-clustering-of-image-keypoints)  
Now form another function I want to pass 3D data (with x,y & z coordinates) using Point3f. But I am not sure if I can do that or not?
If I directly use Point3f for this, it shows error.

Comment: Sorry but your question does not make any sense. KeyPoint in OpenCV works on 2D image. For one 2D image coordinate, you have an infinite number of 3D points along the image ray. Just get rid of the `z` component as **already said** or use `PCL` library if you want to compute/extract 3D keypoints. If you just want **a container/object** that is called `KeyPoint`, just inherit from `KeyPoint` and add a `Point3f` member or create one by yourself from scratch.

Comment: the link you posted works for 2d points. Try to understand the code and think about what changes have to be done to use Point3f instead of KeyPoint within that code.

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: Why don't you write your own `struct` or `class` that incorporates a `Point3f`? `Keypoint` is a relatively short data structure to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way you can use `Point3f` with `KeyPoint`.
`KeyPoint` is only for 2D data and not 3D. You can read the full manual [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html)

Comment: and as already said in other comments you can convert your data into 2D.